# AWS Amplify Cognito: set value MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS' on signup

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I want to create a user and set the value "MessageAction = 'SUPPRESS'" to avoid sending the verification email. This is because I want to send it manually in the CustomMessage trigger.

I've already tested setting it in the options or outside, but the typing does not seem to accept it:

```
await signUp({
        username,
        password,
   
        options: {
          //MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
          userAttributes:{
            email: username,
          },
        },
        
      }
```

How can I do this?
I'm using the latest version of aws-amplify: 6.0.17 in Typescript.